# SQLite3 + CakePHP 1.3.10 - how to?

Tags: cakephp, sqlite

**SOLVED** so i forgot to `sudo apt-get php5-sqlite`
also. downvoters gonna downvote :D

(fyi, i feel bad everytime i use "StackOverload". bad as in, 'i have been hammering for five hours and the nail doesnt seem to fit. but it does! i seez it does!'.)

Summed up, because people might think i'm ranting. (and i wasnt, it was something like 2~3am when i wrote this. i had kind of a fantastical mind at that time)

I cannot, for the love of god, install this shinanigan. I use apache2.
http://www.github.com/cakephp/datasources

---

So, i know that cake doesnt support sqlite [or didn't, back in 2010] but i've seen the Datasources plugin.

Appart from cakephp, when extracted, having 3 seperate plugin folders and the readme.md (seriously, they named the file MD. MD!) stating "extract to plugins folder" and me starting to get all jawed down on first approach;

I tried. i bounced around, i read and tried; i tried every possible configuration, i've mixed configuration steps (hey, one gets desperate.), i've even screamed [and that didnt work either, surprisingly]

Nothing. Besides reading reports of people (wizards, probably!) successfully connecting cakePHP and SQLite3 (with datasources plugin) i myself cannot replicate such marvelous magick. Even with the recipe.

And, here's the plugin i'm using www.github.com/cakephp/datasources
Also, i fly around using an Apache2. normal Apaches don't cut it.

Could someone, by the love of $input("your god here"), explain me how to make this mumbo jumbo connect and rock mah server sideways?

Very much apreciated :)

---

```
    var $default = array(
            'driver' => 'Datasources.DboSqlite3',
            'persistent' => false,
            'database' => '../config/db.sqlite',
            'connect' => 'sqlite',
    );
```

Also, no error besides the "Cake is NOT able to connect to the database." yellow line.
I do have sqlite AND sqlite3 installed, by sudoaptget method.
Don't know about other connections scripts tho.

Comment: Maybe you can start by giving a link to the exact plugin you're using? Also, what wrong with .md? It stands for markdown and conveys the format of the content. A little less ranty and more facts please.

Comment: i wasn't ranting, fine sir. I do, how ever, apologise for forgetting to link you to the real thing. It has been fixed in the first post aswell, https://github.com/cakephp/datasources

Also. when i first read 'md' anywhere, "markdown" is not what comes to mind, and so i laugh at it a bit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I haven't worked with Cake + Sqlite yet, but I surmised the following:

- download the plugin from https://github.com/cakephp/datasources into `app/plugins` so you have the folder structure `app/plugins/datasources/models/...`
- configure a source in `app/config/database.php` to use the `driver` `Datasources.DboSqlite3`, as described in http://book.cakephp.org/view/922/Database-Configuration

  - the parameters are not really documented, but if you look at https://github.com/cakephp/datasources/blob/master/models/datasources/dbo/dbo_sqlite3.php#L57 you see the possible values
  - an example should look like this:

    ```
    public $default = array('driver'     => 'Datasources.DboSqlite3',
                            'persistent' => false,
                            'database'   => '/path/to/your/database/file',
                            'connect'    => 'sqlite');
    ```

The `connect` setting may be tricky, since PHP has different Sqlite drivers for different versions which may or may not be installed. Try to establish a connection using a non-Cake script to test which driver works for you (or if you have any installed at all), then choose `sqlite` or `sqlite2` (as per the comment in the source).

If that doesn't work, please give some concrete information on what you tried, what didn't work, errors etc.

Comment: I forgot that comments for answering with a bigass answer and config files suck. I've updated 1st Post to answer your.

Thanks, btw :)

Comment: i hate when i need to double post, but. I got that far on the configuration part by reading it up too. I didnt got on the "connect => sqlite" but it doesnt seem to affect the database.php configuration the slightest.

Comment: Hey, thanks for telling me what you already knew after I told you what you already knew. Please post these things from the beginning next time, m'kay? :-( Have you tried an *absolute* database path? The relative `../config/` may not go where you think it goes.

Comment: Ok. Sorry fr taking such a long time and whatnot.
uppon using /var/www/b/app/config [where db.sqlite is] cannot connect. So, i went and made it in webroot. no luck either.

the thing is i dont have any errors whatsoever

Comment: Thanks Deceze. if it werent for you, i'd never check if php5-sqlite/3 was here :)